# Saved video doesn't have the same duration as streamed video from a camera

Tags: c++, opencv, save, video-capture, video-processing

I have a question about saving a video with openCV in C++ (I'm using Linux Ubuntu).

I was trying to save a stream from open camera for some time. I finally succeeded, but now I have really not many ideas why the saved stream doesn't have the same duration as I was streaming from my camera. When I am streaming for 10 seconds it has only for example 2-3 seconds and looks like it is accelerated.

Does anybody have some clue what could be the problem? Something wrong in my code or maybe computing performance, maybe the system doesn't save every frame?

Thanks for your help.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>     // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat)
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>  // Video write
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat capture;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened())
{
        cout<<"Cannot connect to camera"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 

    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); 
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); 

    Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));

    VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("/home/Stream_video/cpp/Cam/out.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frameSize,true);

    if ( !oVideoWriter.isOpened() ) {
        cout << "ERROR: Failed to write the video" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while(true){
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video
        if (!bSuccess) {
            cout << "ERROR: Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
            break; //if not success, break loop
        }

        oVideoWriter.write(frame); //writer the frame into the file

        imshow("Display", frame); 

        if (waitKey(10) == 27) {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your capture code is simply too slow to be able to capture all frames. Step 1) would be making sure you are running an optimized build of your code, not a debug build.

Comment: streaming is mostly done at 30-60 fps. while reading without manually setting the fps will be much faster. i would suggest make short video where you count to 5 with your fingers. then check the frames that you can see that you count to 5 with fingers.

Comment: either your capturing is too slow, your streaming is losing frames, or your video file framerate is selected too high.

Comment: I could solve it by changing the value "20" in third parameter in VideoWriter. So I compared duration of saved video with real seconds on my watch and found the right satisfactory value / result. 

Thank You for your helps.